# Upgrading CiviCRM from 4.6.25 to 4.7.15 fails on database upgrade

Tags: upgrade, database

I am running a CiviCRM upgrade on Joomla from 4.6.25 to 4.7.15. The environment is:

Joomla : 3.6.5
PHP : 5.5.9
Database 5.5.52
Apache 2.4.7

PHP Memory 512M
Execution timeout 240

Installing the upgraded component works fine. I clear out the templates_c cache. I then run the database upgrade script and get the following error:

[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.alpha1: SQL]

Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error

Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error

Mode    16

UserInfo    ALTER TABLE `civicrm_action_schedule` ADD COLUMN `filter_contact_language` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Used for multilingual installation' [nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'filter_contact_language']
DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE `civicrm_action_schedule` ADD COLUMN `filter_contact_language` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Used for multilingual installation' 
[nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'filter_contact_language']

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown

Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  unknown:unknown
1   call_user_func(Array, Object(DB_Error)) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:921
2   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'ALTER TABLE `civ…')    /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:985
3   DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, Array, 'ALTER TABLE`civ…')   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:575
4   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -1, null, null, 'ALTER TABLE `civ…', 'DB_Error', true)   unknown:unknown
5   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:224
6   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
7   PEAR->raiseError(null, -1, null, null, 'ALTER TABLE`civ…', 'DB_Error', true)   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
8   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, null, '1060 ** Duplicat…')    /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:933
9   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:403
10  DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('ALTER TABLE `civ…') /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
11  DB_common->query('ALTER TABLE`civ…')   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php:353
12  CRM_Utils_File::sourceSQLFile('mysql://joomcivi…', '-- Add new colum…', null, true) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:196
13  CRM_Upgrade_Form->source('-- Add new colum…', true) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:387
14  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processLocales('/var/www/joomla/…', '4.7.alpha1') /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:421
15  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processSQL('4.7.alpha1')  /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/Base.php:80
16  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_Base::runSql(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '4.7.alpha1')   unknown:unknown
17  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
18  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
19  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
20  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
21  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
22  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  unknown:unknown
23  call_user_func(Array)   /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:276
24  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
25  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
26  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:121
27  civicrm_invoke()    /var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40
28  require_once('/var/www/joomla/…')   /var/www/joomla/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:405
29  JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/var/www/joomla/…') /var/www/joomla/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:380
30  JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_civicrm')    /var/www/joomla/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:98
31  JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()   /var/www/joomla/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:152
32  JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()  /var/www/joomla/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:261
33  JApplicationCms->execute()  /var/www/joomla/administrator/index.php:51
34  {main}

Does anyone have an ideas how to resolve this ? I notice the multilingual errors. This has been installed on the server.

Regards

Damian

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\4.7.alpha1.msg_template** directory

In **civicrm_msg_template.tpl** find the SQL statement that failed and that will indicate the problem.

I had a similar situation where I was forced to upgrade from 4.4 to 4.7.7. I was forced to make corrections and continue the upgrade by commenting out code. Not a process I recommend, but I had no choice. Not recommended for an amateur coder.